# Printing a string in reverse

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder

I am trying to write a simple program to reverse a string and I am having trouble with using `StringBuilder`, as I am not sure how to use it correctly.

```
public class Reverse3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        char[] name = {'S', 't', 'e', 'v', 'e'};

        for(char c = 0; c < name.length; c++){
            System.out.println(name[c]);
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name);
        System.out.println(Builder.reverse());
    }
}
```

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials - The StringBuilder Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html)

Comment: `Builder.reverse()` suggests that you need few steps back to tutorial about objects, references, classes (basics of OOP).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `StringBuilder` constructor that takes a `char[]`. You can append the characters in your loop. And either use an `int` for your loop counter like,

```
char[] name = "Steve".toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    sb.append(name[i]);
}
System.out.println(sb.reverse());
```

**or** use a `for-each` loop like

```
char[] name = "Steve".toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : name) {
    sb.append(ch);
}
System.out.println(sb.reverse());
```

Both output

```
evetS
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the char array to a string.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(new String(name));
System.out.println(sb.reverse().toString());
```

Comment: hey! thanks for this it definitely works a lot better now. Quick question,,, what if I want the name spelled out each on their own line, would i do like a input.nextLine() ???

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant. Did you mean to print out the reversed string? If so you just do the same thing but you convert the string to a char[]. char[] reverseNameArray = sb.reverse().toString().toCharArray(); and then use a for loop on the char[]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert array to stringbuilder directly .

Instead please use this.

```
public static void main(String []args){

    char[] name = {'S', 't', 'e', 'v', 'e'};

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(char c = 0; c < name.length; c++){
        sb.append(name[c]);
        System.out.println(name[c]);
    }

    System.out.println(sb.reverse());

 }
```

Happy Coding... :)